# Can't change powershell version

Tags: powershell

I have a Windows 10 machine that is running Powershell version 5. When I type in `$psversiontable`, I get:

```
    PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $psversiontable

 Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.14393.1198
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.14393.1198
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

When I try to change version by typing in `powershell -version 4.0`, I still get this:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $psversiontable

 Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.14393.1198
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.14393.1198
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

Do you know how I can run version 4?

Thanks!

Comment: This may be a bug in PS5; I can run `-version 2.0` and have it work, but `-version 3.0` or `-version 4.0` respond as you report.

Comment: I only have 4.0 installed and i can do this with 2.0, but not 3.0.

Comment: There's relevant information at https://www.sapien.com/blog/2015/12/21/where-are-v3-and-v4-powershell-versions-in-powershell-studio/ - it applies to PowerShell globally, not just PSStudio. Apparently, the behavior above is works-as-designed.

Comment: thank you, and thanks to @Adamar

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is you can't. There is only a special mode for version 2.0.

Otherwise PowerShell is extremely backwards compatible. Even further PowerShell 3.0 and 4.0 can't be installed side-by-side. Sapien wrote a great [blog post covering additional details on this](https://www.sapien.com/blog/2015/12/21/where-are-v3-and-v4-powershell-versions-in-powershell-studio/)

In general barring a very few outlier bugs, code written for PowerShell 3.0 or 4.0 will work with 5.0/5.1